# Mapstruct Implementation

Tags: spring, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct to map my model to my DTO.
I want to search for a record by the full name.
I do not understand why I get the following errors:

```
Error creating bean with name 'customerController'
Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl'
Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository'
No property name found for type Customer!
```

this is my project

```
public interface CustomerMapper {

    CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CustomerMapper.class);
    @Mapping(source = "lastName", target = "lastName")
    CustomerDTO customerToCustomerDTO(Customer customer);
}
```

```
@Data
public class CustomerDTO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerListDTO {
    List<CustomerDTO> categories;
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")

public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerService customerService;


    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDTO> getCustomerByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                customerService.getCustomerByName(name), HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
```

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    Customer findByName(String x);
}
```

```
public interface CustomerService {
    CustomerDTO getCustomerByName(String name);
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    CustomerMapper customerMapper;
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public CustomerDTO getCustomerByName(String lastName) {
        return customerMapper.customerToCustomerDTO(customerRepository.findByName(lastName));
    }
}
```

This is a potential fix: would be to map the below in the CustomerMapper, but to me it doesn't feel right.

```
@Mapping(source = "name", target = "lastName")
@Mapping(source = "firstName", target = "firstName")
```

In the documentation, it is said that you can map whatever field from model to DTO, I think there might be something wrong in my code.
The way I try implementing in the repo, service, controller.

Edit:

Maybe a solution would be to use DTO in Repository?

Update:

```
@Override
    public CustomerDTO getCustomerByName(String lastName) {
        return customerRepository.findByName(lastName).map(customerMapper::customerToCustomerDTO);
    }
```

.map cannot be used.

for .map to be used I should use code like this

```
    .findAll()
    .stream()
    .map(customerMapper::customerToCustomerDTO)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am using the findByName method however, that doesn't have access to .map.

How can I solve that problem?

**EDIT**

this is how my Customer I think should look like

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerDTO {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No property name found for type Customer!"

In you table costumer you have a column with name "**name**"?

Below I made some changes in your code, however if you need to find by name your repository needs to find correct search. When you use findByName only return rows where name is equals to name passed in parameter. Example: findByName("Scilla") only return rows where column name is equals to "Scilla", if a column name have values like "scilla" (lower) or "Scilla abc" this entries was not returned by query.

Method findByName with value "Scilla" generate this query:

```sql
select * from customer where name = 'Scilla';
```

#### Code changes

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    
    Customer findByLastName(String lastName);
    
    List<Customer> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);

    List<Customer> findByLastNameContaining(String name);

}
```

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {

    CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CustomerMapper.class);

    CustomerDTO customerToCustomerDTO(Customer customer);

    Customer toDomain(CustomerDTO customerDTO);
    
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;
    
}
```

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class CustomerDTO {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerService customerService;


    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDTO> getCustomerByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                customerService.getCustomerByName(name), HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDTO> getCustomerByName(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                customerService.save(customerDTO), HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
    
}
```

#### Important

Below put Spring Data query and translation query.

```java
List<Customer> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name)
```

```sql
select * from customer where last_name ilike = '%name%';
```

**pom.xml definition**

```xml
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I am sorry I think your post is redundant, as what you did, I proposed as a solution in my question.

Comment: You need to look with more attention, I made some changes to remove errors and use correctly mapstruct. To search by full name you need to be more specific, the column name have full name? You want to find with like or ilike approach?

Comment: Check my latest EDIT. 
That is how my Customer should look like. 
I want to map the lastName from customer to lastName in DTO. When I do that i get the errors I menton.

using your return from getCustomerByName, get's me the same errors.

Comment: If Dto object field have same name that field in domain object you do not need to use "@Mapping" annotation, in my answer I edited CustomerMapper to remove "@Mapping" annotation. Can you share you database table creation? because if you have "@Entity" costumer with lastName in table costumer you need to have a column with name "last_name" or define name of column with "@Column" annotation. And in your repository you need to change findByName to findByLastName.

Comment: Removing @Mapping did not solve the problem.
I don't have a table creation. I am using H2 in memory. 
It becomes clear the problem is that the return in getCustomerByName in your case doesn't know how to map it to lastName.

Comment: I edited all solution to add H2 implementation and pom.xml definition. After making the changes you need to compile the project with maven "mvn clean install".

Comment: Good job Luis. I marked your answer as correct. What i learned is, that i don't need to use the @Mapping annotation if the model fields are exactly the same as in the DTO.

I have created a separate project, running just your code. Apparently there is a bug in my parent project where I deal with other controllers as well, that I will have to find.

Comment: I have a question off topic. Any article or code that deals with one mandatory field and optional fields for querying, you could point to?. At the moment I do a GET. My next challenge would be to to a get based on lastName and maybe postCode.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any article to this purpose. To see how you can write queries with spring data I use Spring Data documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html). To complex queries I use jooq and with him I can add only the conditions that I want. With Spring Data you can implement conditions in service and call different repository queries based on inserted fields. Example if zipCode is null you call findByLastName, when you have boot call findByLastNameAndZipCode.

Comment: Another thing you should be aware is when you make queries to fields that are not unique or primary key, you can have more than one entry in the database that respects the where condition. In this cases you can not map to a object and need map to a List, for example use "List<Customer> findByName" instead "Customer findByName".

Comment: Thank you. I am sure i will come to a point where I will come back to read your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To map your Customer entity to DTO and use it in the Spring application you should use the following mapper (with parameter `componentModel` = "spring"):

```java
@Mapper(
    componentModel = "spring",
    nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT,
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS,
    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE
)
public interface CustomerMapper {
   @Mapping(target = "lastName", source = "name")
   CustomerDto toDto(Customer customer);
}
```

MapStruct doesn't know how to map `name` property in your entity to `lastName` property in the DTO, so you have to specify this in @Mapping annotation.

(I also recommend to use specified values of 'strategy' parameters - you can check their purpose in javadoc.)

In this case, MapStruct generates an appropriate Spring bean with the implementation of your mapper, something like this:

```java
@Component
public class CustomerMapperImpl {

    public CustomerDto toDto(Customer customer) {
        CustomerDto dto = new CustomerDto();
        if (customer != null) {
            if (customer.getFirstName() != null) {
                dto.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
            }
            if (customer.getName() != null) {
                dto.setLastName(customer.getName());
            }        
        }
        return dto;
    }
}
```

So Spring will be able to inject that bean in your service (don't forget to correct `findByName` method of your repo to return `Optional`):

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implement CustomerService {

    private final CustomerRepo repo;
    private final CustomerMapper mapper;

    @Override 
    public Optional<CustomerDto> getByName(@NonNull String name) {
        return repo.findByName(name).map(mapper::toDto)
    }
    
    @Override 
    public List<CustomerDto> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll().stream().map(mapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And then use this service in your REST controller:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerService service;

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public CustomerDto getByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return service.getByName()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException("Customer not found"));
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<CustomerDto> getAll() {
        return service.getAll();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to configure your project to use MapStruct and Lombok together:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: I think I might have made you missing the point.
What I was saying is that this implementation is wrong.
''name'' in Customer class should be lastName.

so, that is when i get the errors. I apologies, i must have copied the Customer class that was fixing the problem.

Comment: Even so. findByNAme(name).map can't be resolved.

The CustomerMapperImp is a class generated by the map construct, so it is redundant. I have that.

Comment: However there are some additional tips in your response to make this more robust! But the problem is not solved.